# Doctrine не видит мой кастомный класс и ее функции из Repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine2, repository, symfony4

Вот мой Entity

```
/**
     * @package App\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="bankkurs")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BankursRepository")
     */
    class BankKurs
    {
    ..............
    }
```

Тут мой репозиторий

```
    <?php

namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\BankKurs;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;

class BankursRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, BankKurs::class);
    }

    public function getReallKurs($data)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('b')
            ->from('App:BankKurs', 'b')
            ->where(' date = :date')
            ->setParameter('date',  $data );

        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

Так я пытаюсь получить доступ к моей функции

```
public function getRealKursAction()
{
    $value = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(BankKurs::class)->getReallKurs(мой параметр);
    return $this->handleView($this->view($value));
}
```

Мой класс в репозитории вообще не распознается. При наведении мышкой на мою функцию говорит что

```
method getReallKurs not found in doctrine common persistence Objectrepository
```

мой bundles.php

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
];
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте выполнить данную инструкцию и проверить что находится в переменной `$value = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(BankKurs::class);`

Comment: Когда я вызываю стандартные методы то они работают корректно(findAll,findbyID и.т.д)

Answer (score 0):

Думаю не совсем лучшее решение, но все же оно имеет место быть. 
И так чтобы функция видела ваш Repository можно передать его в качестве параметра как показано ниже и уже дальше использовать его методы.

```
/**
 * 
 * @Rest\Get("/realkusrs")
 *
 * @return Response
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function getRealKursAction(BankursRepository $repository)
{

     $now = new DateTime();
     $value =  $repository->getReallKurs($now);

     return $this->handleView($this->view($value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А почему такие странные вызовы getManager, ведь в symfony4 почти везде autoload? Может не те экземпляры такими методами и вызываете.

Например в BankursRepository запись скорее всего должна быть такой

```
public function getReallKurs($data)
{
    $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
       ->where('b.date = :date')
       ->setParameter('date',  $data );

    return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Да и использование выглядит странно

```
$value = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(BankKurs::class)->getReallKurs(мой параметр);
```

А почему EntityManager не через autoload в конструкторе подключен?

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы вызываете функцию через длинную цепочку флюентов, то IDE не может угадать, какой класс будет возвращен генератором. IDE видит только интерфейс, определенный в return функции getRepository. Поэтому у вас видятся стандартные `find`, `findAll`.

Если хотитье, чтобы IDE давала правильные подсказки, то сделайте так:

```
/** @var BankursRepository $repo */
$repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(BankKurs::class);
$value = $repo->getReallKurs(мой параметр);
```